# Google Geo Chart

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm using Google's Geo Charts API, and using json to update the data.

This is my map js (map.php):

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "includes/_ajax_home_map.php?metric=Clicks",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;  

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);      
    var options = {
        //region: '009',
        backgroundColor: 'EAF7FE',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['910101']}
        };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

This is my php generated json (_ajax_home_map.php):

```
$data = '{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Country","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Popularity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [';


$metric = $_REQUEST['roi_tag'];

$sql = "SELECT SUM($metric) as '$metric',tag_1 FROM Dashboard_ClientsCampaigns_Today_HoH WHERE tag_1 != '' GROUP BY tag_1";
$sql = mysql_query($sql);

$count = 1;


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $tag_1 = strtoupper($row["tag_1"]);
    if($tag_1 == "UK")$tag_1 = "GB";
    if($count != 1)$data .= ",";
    $count++;
    $data .= '{"c":[{"v":"'.$tag_1.'","f":null},{"v":'.$row[$metric].',"f":null}]}';
}

$data .= ']}';

echo $data;
```

Now when I connect these 2, I just get a blank map.  No data is in there.  BUT..here comes the strange part.  If I browse directly to my PHP JSON, I get this:

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"Country","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"Popularity","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [{"c":[{"v":"AU","f":null},{"v":139,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"CZ","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"DE","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"DK","f":null},{"v":978,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"ES","f":null},{"v":32,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"HU","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"IE","f":null},{"v":65,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"IT","f":null},{"v":5081,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"PT","f":null},{"v":4452,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"RO","f":null},{"v":16,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"RS","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"RU","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"SE","f":null},{"v":69,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"GB","f":null},{"v":28123,"f":null}]}]}
```

If I take this outputted JSON, copy it, home it in it's own file (data2.php), then get my map js to access it, it populates the map perfectly.

How on earth can I have 2 pieces of identical JSON and only one work with Google Charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you try to load the PHP with the wrong param

```
_ajax_home_map.php?metric=Clicks
```

but in the code you look for

```
$metric = $_REQUEST['roi_tag'];
```

try

```
$metric = $_REQUEST['metric'];
```

..instead. And you are right by the way - the JSON works just fine! Thats not the problem.

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  I was pulling my hair out!!